# unneccessary space between parent div and image thats inside of it

Tags: html, css

html code

```
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>


<title>abc</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="box"><img src="images/roundlogo.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css code

```
img{
border:0px;
border-image-width:0px;
border-image-slice:0px;

}
.box
{
width:250px;
//border:1px solid;
height:auto;
border-image-slice:0px;
border-image-width:0px;
border-image-outset:0px;
}

.box img
{
width:100%;
//border:1px solid green;
margin-top:0px;
}
```

i write code shown upper 
but when checking browser there is 4px space between image and parent div() called box

here is my work in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/2RqmU/547/
you can inspect  iframe which was the result are shown 
this shows that space clearly
http://jsfiddle.net/2RqmU/548/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The img is an inline element. To remove the extra space either make it a block element or give it a vertical alignment other than baseline.

Comment: thx
when image is inline how there is a 4px space between image and parent div?

Comment: ah i got it now it is the space which belongs to word space

Answer (score 1):

Just give `block` to that image.

`img{ display:block; }`

There `div` consider that `image` as `inline element`. So it doesn't consider image's height for set it's height (example: by default, text is inline element. parent element of the text, never has height as same as text height).

These things also worked for me.

```
display: inherit (or) grid (or) table-caption (or) list-item;

(or)

vertical-align: bottom;
```